# Stata: Difference in Difference; common-trend plot

Tags: regression, stata, difference-in-difference, identifiability

I estimate the following flexible difference-in-difference model with Stata:

```
regress Y i.time i.time##i.treatment
```

Starting from this model, I'd like to generate two plots:

1) The first plot shows the prediction of the previous model separately for the control and treatment group. For that purpose, I use the margins command:

```
margins time#treatment
```

For visibility of the common trend, I want to plot the predicted outcome in each period relative to its pre-treatment value. I could not find any way to achieve this directly in the margins command (is there any?). Therefore, I use the following work-around: (a) save the results (predictions) of the margin command in a matrix. (b) divide the (predicted) outcome in the treatment group by its pre-treatment value. (c) divide the (predicted) outcome in the control group by its pre-treatment value. I then plot both modified predictions as a function of time.

2) The second plot aims at visualizing the treatment effect over time. For that purpose, I want to divide the series obtained in step (b) by the series obtained in step (c). Put differently, the graph for the treatment effect also should be normalized to the pre-treatment period. While I can easily divide the two series (by using the values stored in matrices), I don't know how to calculate standard errors in this case with Stata.

I am very thankful for your help!